# Android ListView wrong Item Update

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, bluetooth

First off all i'll explain what i want to do and i will post the code bellow.
I have a Bluetooth Service, a ListView with a Custom Adapter and a Handler for the bluetooth Service which will notify if the phone is Connected || Connecting || Disconected form a BT Device.

My ListView contains the bluetooth devices nearby, on Click the item lable for example, is updated and the phone will connect to that device.

Let's say I have 2 BT Devices. If i will select the first the label of the first will be updated (which is correct), **BUT if i select the item no. 2, for some reason it update's also the first lable <- THIS IS THE PROBLEM**

I use fragments in my app, the code for the ListViewAdapter and method to update below:

**LIST VIEW ADAPTER CODE:**

```
public class BluetoothListViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<HashMap<String, String>>{

    Context ctx;
    private Activity activity;
    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
    private LayoutInflater inflater = null;
    CircularProgressButton Device = null;

    public BluetoothListViewAdapter(Activity a, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> d) {
        super(a,R.layout.template_bluetooth_listview_element,d);

        ctx = a.getBaseContext();
        activity = a;
        data = d;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) a.getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return data.size();
    }



    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
       String TAG;
       String MAC;

        View vi = convertView;

        if (vi == null)
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.template_bluetooth_listview_element, null);

        Device = null;
        Device = (CircularProgressButton) vi.findViewById(R.id.CircularProgressButton_BluetoothListElement);



        HashMap<String, String> category = new HashMap<String, String>();
        category = data.get(position);

        TAG = (category.get("TAG"));
        MAC = (category.get("MAC"));

        Device.setText(TAG + "\n" + MAC);
        Device.setIdleText(TAG + "\n" + MAC);

        if(GlobalActivity.CurrentDeviceTAG.equals(TAG) && GlobalActivity.CurrentDeviceMAC.equals(MAC) && position == GlobalActivity.CurrentDevicePosition) { // if the selected device is the one i am connected

            if (GlobalActivity.BluetoothConnectionStatus == GlobalActivity.STATE_CONNECTED) {
                Device.setIndeterminateProgressMode(false);
                Device.setProgress(100); // -- update GUI Element
            }

            if (GlobalActivity.BluetoothConnectionStatus == GlobalActivity.STATE_NONE) {
                Device.setIndeterminateProgressMode(false);
                Device.setProgress(0); // -- update GUI Element
            }

        }

        return vi;
    }

}
```

**BLUETOOTH FRAGMENT CODE (position was saved on connection try in a public static int):**

```
public void BluetoothStateChanged(int position){
        Adapter.getView(position, null, null);
        Adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        BluetoothDeviceListView.setAdapter(Adapter);


    }
```

The above method is called by the Bluetooth Service handler on State Change - this one update's the GUI element.

Sorry for my bad english and explanations. I have 27H with no sleep.

I really need to fix this.

Thank you for your Time

**UPDATE ON REQUEST - LISTVIEW ITEM LAYOUT:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#424242">

    <com.dd.CircularProgressButton
        android:id="@+id/CircularProgressButton_BluetoothListElement"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:cpb_cornerRadius="48dp"
        app:cpb_iconComplete="@drawable/ic_action_accept"
        app:cpb_iconError="@drawable/ic_action_cancel"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:clickable="false" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: && position == GlobalActivity.CurrentDevicePosition . May I know significance of this and where is this managed

Comment: position is the one given on item click;
GlobalActivity.CurrentDevicePosition is the one of the Current connected device. So if they equals the that is 100% the item of with GUI i want to update

Comment: why are you calling `Adapter.getView`??

Comment: @Boss because it is not updateing if i use the code in the fragment and i call directly notifydatachenged() - don't know why

Comment: You shouldn't call that method by yourself. its invoked by the system itself. I think you shouldn't mess with it.

Comment: To update the list, You should add some data to your list and then call `notifyDatasetChanged`..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public void BluetoothStateChanged(){
        int start = BluetoothDeviceListView.getFirstVisiblePosition();
        for(int i = start, j = BluetoothDeviceListView.getLastVisiblePosition(); i<=j; i++) {
            View view = BluetoothDeviceListView.getChildAt(i - start);
            if ((BluetoothDeviceListView.getItemAtPosition(i)) != null) {
                BluetoothDeviceListView.getAdapter().getView(i, view, BluetoothDeviceListView); // Tell the adapter to update this view
            }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a class with a progressbar and whenever you create a view in getView() set this holder class as a tag.

See following code:

```
public class BluetoothListViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<HashMap<String, String>>{

    Context ctx;
    private Activity activity;
    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
    private LayoutInflater inflater = null;

    public BluetoothListViewAdapter(Activity a, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> d) {
        super(a,R.layout.template_bluetooth_listview_element,d);

        ctx = a.getBaseContext();
        activity = a;
        data = d;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) a.getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    } 

    @Override 
    public int getCount() { 
        return data.size();
    } 



    @Override 
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    } 


    @Override 
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
       String TAG;
       String MAC;

        View vi = convertView;
        Holder holder;
        if (vi == null)
        {
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.template_bluetooth_listview_element, null);
            holder.Device = (CircularProgressButton) vi.findViewById(R.id.CircularProgressButton_BluetoothListElement); 
            vi.setTag(holder);
        }
        else
            holder = (Holder) vi.getTag();


        HashMap<String, String> category = new HashMap<String, String>();
        category = data.get(position);

        TAG = (category.get("TAG"));
        MAC = (category.get("MAC"));

        holder.Device.setText(TAG + "\n" + MAC);
        holder.Device.setIdleText(TAG + "\n" + MAC);

        if(GlobalActivity.CurrentDeviceTAG.equals(TAG) && GlobalActivity.CurrentDeviceMAC.equals(MAC) && position == GlobalActivity.CurrentDevicePosition) { // if the selected device is the one i am connected

            if (GlobalActivity.BluetoothConnectionStatus == GlobalActivity.STATE_CONNECTED) { 
                holder.Device.setIndeterminateProgressMode(false);
                holder.Device.setProgress(100); // -- update GUI Element
            } 

            if (GlobalActivity.BluetoothConnectionStatus == GlobalActivity.STATE_NONE) { 
                holder.Device.setIndeterminateProgressMode(false);
                holder.Device.setProgress(0); // -- update GUI Element
            } 

        } 

        return vi;
    } 

    class Holder{
        CircularProgressButton Device;
    }
}
```

Comment: the progressbar is a free library. It is a button which on click is changing to a circle progress bar ->
this one: https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/67

Comment: can you update your question with xml layout you are using?

Comment: DONE :) check the question :)

Comment: Where is the label that you are talking about?

Comment: there is no lable it was an example. Let's say i want to change the progress. Because accordin to the lable this how the button drawable is changed

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86993/discussion-between-iosif-bancioiu-and-chandil03).